# Windows 8 via VirtualBox - Metro apps won't open when clicked

Tags: windows-8-preview, modern-ui

When running the Windows 8 developer preview via VirtualBox, Metro apps don't seem to open when I click them. Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Additionally in the traditional UI mode, I can't seem to open the old fashioned Start Menu, nor can I find any apps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems you need to set the resolution of the virtual machine to at least 1024x768 to run the apps.

Comment: Can you please tell us what resolution you need to set it to for the apps to be supported?

Comment: I just set it to the highest one available.

Comment: You need to set it to 1024x768.  That's the minimum Metro supports.  If you have it set to a lower resolution, nothing will happen if you click on an icon (I guess they'll have to figure something new to communicate the error, now that they've forbidden dialog boxes).

Comment: Damn, wish I'd known this before installing on my 1024x600 netbook :P

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the resolution to a minimum of 1024x768 to run Metro apps.  If you have it set to something lower, the app just won't launch and no error message will be displayed.