# Metro Apps do not open in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8-preview, modern-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 8 via VirtualBox - Metro apps won't open when clicked](https://superuser.com/questions/335603/windows-8-via-virtualbox-metro-apps-wont-open-when-clicked)

My monitor resolution is set to 1280 * 720. I cannot open any <s>Metro</s> Windows-8 style UI apps, because I keep getting

> Screen resolution is too low for this app to run

error message. What resolution should I set for Windows-8 style UI apps to run?

[image]

[image]

Display Properties

> Your resolution is lower than 1024 * 768. Some items might not fit and apps might not open.

My system specifications:

> - Operating System:   Windows 8 Release Preview, 64-bit
> - DirectX version:        11.0
> - GPU processor:        GeForce 210
> - Driver version:         302.82
> - DirectX support:      10.1
> - Total available graphics memory:    2815 MB
> - Dedicated video memory:               1024 MB DDR3
> - System video memory:                   0 MB
> - Shared system memory:                1791 MB

Comment: You are not using a supported resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Your current vertical resolution is 720p and less than the 1024x768 that is [required by "Metro."](https://web.archive.org/web/20151201195134/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx)

Are you unable to change your resolution?  You may need to use a different display device.

You may need to use a "non-recommended" resolution with a vertical resolution of greater than 720 if supported by your AOC-brand monitor.

Comment: Basically, it doesn't matter than your resolution is higher in one direction or that it has more pixels overall - it needs to at least those distances in every dimension.